# GameMaker: 3D floor collision issue

Tags: game-maker

So I'm trying to create 3D collisions for a floor object, and when I jump in-between 2 floor objects, with one being a higher Z axis than the other, as soon as my vertical speed goes even slightly down, I get teleported to be on the floor.
Variable List:
z - Z axis
zspeed - Vertical (Z) speed
grounded - On the ground or not.
Event: Collision with obj_floor

Code:

```
if z = clamp(z,other.z-5,other.z+1) && zspeed < 0 {
    z = other.z;
    grounded = true;
}

else { grounded = false; }

if z = other.z {
    zspeed = 0;
    grounded = true;
}

if z = clamp(z,-5,other.z-2) {
    x=xprevious;
    y=yprevious;
}
```

Is there a solution for this? That'd be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I had a similair question asked about tile collision when falling down, though it was related to a 2D enviroment, but I think you could replace the axis with the z axis to get a similair result https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71982754/2d-continous-collision-detection-in-monogame-xna-framework/71995946#71995946

Comment: Clamp returns a number (the new value of z in your case), not a boolean.  I would suggest that asking Game Maker to cast `clamp(z,-5,other.z-2)` as a boolean (which it will do as you're using it as the expression in the if statement) is your issue.  It's certainly not what you want to be doing.

Answer (score 0):

Try something more like this:

```
if (zspeed > 0 and z > other.z-5 and z < other.z+1) {
   z = other.z;
   grounded = true;
   zspeed = 0;
} else {
   grounded = false;
}
```

Of course there will be other situations outside of this routine where you should should set grounded to false, probably when there is no collision at all.

Basically if the player collides with the platform and is within a certain range of z and is moving downwards (zspeed > 0), set it to z.  Otherwise do nothing.

I have never used zspeed, so I assume zspeed of > 0 is moving "downwards".

As for `clamp` I suspect you have misunderstood what it does.  Your use of it suggests you think that it returns true if z is within the min and max.  What it actually does is provide you a value of z such that is is within min and max.
So if your value of z is 100000, clamp(z, -5, 5) will return 5.  I don't think this is what you want :)

See link:
https://manual.yoyogames.com/GameMaker_Language/GML_Reference/Maths_And_Numbers/Number_Functions/clamp.htm