# Having trouble with wall collisions

Tags: collision, gml, game-maker-studio-2

I'm working on this game right now (with GameMaker Studio 2) and I'm currently coding walls and when I tried making horizontal collision, it worked fine, but when I made floor collision I would get stuck in the walls and floor

here's the code:

```
//input

keyRight = keyboard_check(ord("D"));

keyLeft = keyboard_check(ord("A"));

keyUp = keyboard_check(ord("W"));

keyDown = keyboard_check(ord("S"));

// direction

var move2 = (keyDown - keyUp) * vspd;

var move = (keyRight - keyLeft) * hspd;

//collision stuff idk

if place_meeting ( x + move, y ,obj_wall)


move2= 0;

if place_meeting ( x + move2, y ,obj_wall)

move= 0;
    

// comiit

x += move

y += move2
```

If someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to do it right please tell me I would appreciate it thanks in advance.

Comment: This is JavaScript? You should tag with the appropriate language. You should also put braces around your conditional statements even when it’s not strictly necessary. Makes things much easier to read for you and others.

Comment: This is a common collision problem, maybe this answer can help you out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71982754/2d-continous-collision-detection-in-monogame-xna-framework/71995946#71995946

@miken32 It's GML, a language specific for GameMaker, it can already be assumed it's GML if the question is tagged with GameMaker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are checking for a wall at a horizontal offset in both cases and also move/move2 assignments are mixed up. So, instead of

```
if place_meeting ( x + move, y ,obj_wall)
    move2= 0;

if place_meeting ( x + move2, y ,obj_wall)
    move= 0;
```

you could have

```
if place_meeting ( x + move, y ,obj_wall)
    move= 0;

if place_meeting ( x, y + move2 ,obj_wall)
    move2= 0;
```

Or a small loop if you need the object to approach the collision target.